# change URL in peoplesoft

Tags: peoplesoft

Can someone please tell me if the URLID in URL Maintenance under

```
people tools-->utilities-->administration-->url
```

is updated, will it change the navigation to the updated page?

Answer (score 1):

This URL definitions can be accessed in peoplecode by

```
GetUrl(URL.MY_URL_ID);
```

If a definition is updated the version number is increased, see table:

```
select * from psurldefn
```

After updating an url definition close existing sessions and logon again because this mechanism doesn't work properly.

Be aware of language dependencies:

```
select * from psurldefnlang
```

Comment: Thanks Frank :) I have my URLID, I need to update it with the correct link. can you please tell me the difference between external link static and dynamic? Dynamic is something which is done through peoplecode?

Comment: external static link is controled by URLID in URL Maintenance. Dynamic is done in peoplecode (rowinit event).

Comment: Thanks for your help :)